# How to dynamically name & create sub-object properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, javascript-objects

I have an Object that i will later write to a JSON for storage.  This particular project is for spawning enemies for an rpg-bot I'm making.  I have a "bestiary" with the enemies stats, and I'm trying to spawn multiple enemies in order into an encounter.

Here's a code snippet as it is now:

```js
SpawnEncounter(message, [0, 2, 5, 1], characterInfoJSON, userID, ServerPrefix)

function SpawnEncounter(message, EnemiesIndicies, InfoFile, user, ServerPrefix) {
    // bestiary is a json containing monster statistics.  their keys are numbers
    let bestiary = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./bestiary.json", "utf8"));

    let encounterIntro = [];

    InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter = {};
    InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Target = 0;
    InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Enemies = {};
    
    // EnemiesIndecies is an array of keys, referring to specific monsters in the bestiary
    for (const item in EnemiesIndicies) {
        // Copy the monster stats into one enemy in the encounter
        InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Enemies[item] = bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]];

        // Add a Modifiers object to the enemy
        InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Enemies[item].Modifiers = {
            StrMod: 0,
            DefMod: 0,
            AttackSpeedMod: 0,
            ACMod: 0,
            DmgMod: 0,
            CritMod: 0
        }
        // push the name of the enemy to the list of all enemies that will spawn
        encounterIntro.push(bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]].Name);
    }

    // store the encounter once complete
    fs.writeFile("./playerinfo.json", JSON.stringify(InfoFile), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
    });

    // display the new encounter
    let LastEnemy = encounterIntro.pop()

    if (encounterIntro.length === 0) {
        message.channel.send(`All of a sudden, a ${LastEnemy} appears!\nTo attack it, use \`\`${ServerPrefix}attack\`\``);
    }
    else if (encounterIntro.length >= 1) {
        message.channel.send(`All of a sudden, a ${encounterIntro.join(", ")} and a ${LastEnemy} appears!\nTo attack it, use \`\`${ServerPrefix}attack\`\``);
    }
}
```

What I'm hoping to create is something like this:

```
{
   MyID: {
      CurrentEncounter: {
         Target: 0
         Enemies: {
            0: {insert enemy 0's stats + modifiers},
            1: {insert enemy 2's stats + modifiers},
            2: {insert enemy 5's stats + modifiers},
            3: {insert enemy 1's stats + modifiers}
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I realize that's heavily simplified, but i hope it gets the point across.

My problem is, each time i run this, and i spawn an encounter, it always says the enemies that are *supposed* to appear, are all called "undefined".

I checked the JSON after it was written to, and the structure of the Object is correct, up to Enemies.  It shows that there is an object attributed to Enemies, but it's empty.  There's nothing in it.

This tells me that something is wrong with how I'm spawning the enemies, or assigning information to Enemies's properties, but I can't put my finger on it.  What's worse is that there's no error message to go off.  This must mean my syntax is right, but it's not pulling the bestiary info, or it's not writing it properly...

Can anyone tell me what is wrong, or better yet: propose a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that in one case, when I was calling SpawnEncounter(), I was passing in EnemiesIncdecies as just a number, and not an array of numbers (even if there's only one number in the array).  After passing in an array of numbers, the problem fixed itself, and the code works fine now.

Comment: *sarcasm* Who woulda thought two brackets ("[ ]") could cause a month-long problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const item in EnemiesIndicies) {
    // Copy the monster stats into one enemy in the encounter
    InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Enemies[item] = bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]];

    // Add a Modifiers object to the enemy
    InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Enemies[item].Modifiers = {
        StrMod: 0,
        DefMod: 0,
        AttackSpeedMod: 0,
        ACMod: 0,
        DmgMod: 0,
        CritMod: 0
    };
  
    // push the name of the enemy to the list of all enemies that will spawn
    encounterIntro.push(bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]].Name);
}
```

You're using a For->In loop... each iteration of that loop, "item" is a different value from the EnemiesIndicies array... it is NOT the index of the current item in the array.   When you do:

```
InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Enemies[item] = bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]];
```

and:

```
encounterIntro.push(bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]].Name);
```

you are using item as the index within EnemiesIndicies...  chances are good that the value of item which was one of the values storied in EnemiesIndicies is outside of the number of entries the array... so it isnt a valid index... and even if it was a valid index, it prolly isnt the index of the value itself... the only way it would work as written is if: EnemiesIndicies[0] is 0, and EnemiesIndicies[1] is 1, and EnemiesIndicies[2] is 2, etc....

Consider using a standard for loop instead:

```
let item = 0;
for (item = 0; item < EnemiesIndicies.length; item++) {
    // Copy the monster stats into one enemy in the encounter
    InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Enemies[item] = bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]];
        
    // Add a Modifiers object to the enemy
    InfoFile[user].CurrentEncounter.Enemies[item].Modifiers = {
        StrMod: 0,
        DefMod: 0,
        AttackSpeedMod: 0,
        ACMod: 0,
        DmgMod: 0,
        CritMod: 0
    };
          
    // push the name of the enemy to the list of all enemies that will spawn
    encounterIntro.push(bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]].Name);
}
```

Doing it this way... item is always the index of a value within EnemiesIndicies.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it.  I copied your suggestion to replace my for-in loop, and it still says "All of a sudden, a undefined appears!"

Comment: it's still applying the correct structure, but it's not writing anything to Enemies.

Comment: in the loop, do a console.log(item); console.log(EnemiesIndicies[item]); console.log(bestiary[EnemiesIndicies[item]]); and see what comes back... make sure you're actually passing in the data you think you are...

Comment: I just did the console log that you suggested, but nothing is printing to the console...